# A new table is unexpectedly not sizing up to encompass number of rows being sent by UPDATE / SET / FROM

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, create-table

Disclaimer - very novice SQL programmer here; no formal background.  I think that I am missing something very basic - need help figuring out why a table that I created does not size up automatically (row length) to be able to fit all data that I am trying to send with an UPDATE command.

Background - I created a new database "HelperTables" in SSMS (all settings are default).  I then created a new table with the wizard.  Script for the table is as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CollectionStatus_RecipientGroup]
(
     [RecipientGroup] [VARCHAR](255) NULL,
     [CollectionStatus] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_CollectionStatus_RecipientGroup] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CollectionStatus] ASC)
                     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I am now trying to run an `UPDATE / SET / FROM` query to update this table with a selection.

Code is as follows:

```
UPDATE [HelperTables].[dbo].[CollectionStatus_RecipientGroup]
SET [RecipientGroup] = tableupdate.RecipientGroup,
    [CollectionStatus] = tableupdate.CollectionStatus
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM
         (SELECT /* query trimmed for brevity - I confirmed it works perfectly by itself*/
         ) results
    ) tableupdate
```

On a prior SQL Server, this worked perfectly. However it was resulting in (0 rows affected) return command (no errors) until I went in to the Edit Top XXX Rows wizard and added some dummy data.  When I reran the query, the result was (4 rows affected) with 4 being the number of dummy data rows that I added.  The data being sent by the query does represent the first four rows of the result set.

As such, my conclusion is that my code is fine but something is wrong with either the setup of the table or some inherent setting within SSMS (perhaps permissions?).

What am I missing?

Comment: Block quotes are for quoting, not for code. The code block is for code.

Comment: Are you really asking us to debug a statement that you didn't provide...? We can't tell you why a query isn't working when all we have is *"query trimmed for brevity - I confirmed it works perfectly by itself"*.

Comment: If you created the table but did not insert rows, the update statement will always update zero rows. Rows must first be inserted before they can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all feedback, even the snarky bits. Confirming that INSERT INTO solved the issue - I also added DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE clauses to the same query (in front, obviously). Probably not the most efficient way to do this but seems to work fine. If there is a better way than I would love to learn!